# crop raster using another raster R

Tags: r, maps, r-raster

How can I `crop right raster to extent of left raster` below?
I used:

```
cr <- crop(right, extent(left),snap="out") 
fr <- rasterize(left, cr) 
r<- mask(x=cr, mask=fr)
```

but did not succeed.

Thanks for suggesting a work around.

[image]

Comment: See here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180743/crop-raster-based-on-another-raster-r

Comment: i believe you can just take the extent of your left raster extent(left) and use it in the crop function : crop(right, extent(left))

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer by using `cr <- crop(right, extent(-141.01807 , -52.61941, 41.68144, 60), snap="out")` but I guess there should be a clever way to use the extent of the raster itself and not of the shapefile via visual inspection

[image]

Comment: See here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180743/crop-raster-based-on-another-raster-r